# Unable to start Group Replication for instance 'xxxxx:3306'?

Tags: mysql, mysql-group-replication, mysql-innodb-cluster

I am trying to do a innodb cluster installation on mysql and it keeps showing this error message:

> 2019-11-13T18:39:04.599509Z 15 [ERROR] [MY-011640] [Repl] Plugin
>   group_replication reported: 'Timeout on wait for view after joining
>   group' 2019-11-13T18:39:04.599604Z 15 [ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl]
>   Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] The member is leaving a
>   group without being on one.' 2019-11-13T18:58:09.097406Z 0 [System]
>   [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld
>   8.0.18)  MySQL Community Server - GPL. 2019-11-13T18:58:09.513421Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.18)
>   starting as process 11847 2019-11-13T18:58:09.869423Z 0 [ERROR]
>   [MY-013180] [Server] Function 'group_replication' already exists.
>   2019-11-13T18:58:09.869563Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010736] [Server] Couldn't
>   load plugin named 'group_replication' with soname
>   'group_replication.so'. 2019-11-13T18:58:09.954250Z 0 [Warning]
>   [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
>   2019-11-13T18:58:09.980142Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010604] [Repl] Neither
>   --relay-log nor --relay-log-index were used; so replication may break when this MySQL server acts as a slave and has his hostname changed!!
>   Please use '--relay-log=inmbz7200-relay-bin' to avoid this problem.
>   2019-11-13T18:58:09.986045Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.18'  socket:
>   '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting that is a server joining and it does not able to contact/receive information from member of the group.

Do you confirmed that they are able to connect?

You can give a look into https://mysqlhighavailability.com/setting-up-mysql-group-replication-with-mysql-docker-images/ to a tutorial on trying group replication with docker.